# Revel - Storing an object in session

Tags: session, go, revel

I'm using the oauth package "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth" with revel and the it creates a few structures with quite a bit of information in it. I need this information to be persistent throughout the session but sessions can only be type string. Is there a better way of doing this than the following?

```
c.Session["AccessToken"] = t.Token.AccessToken
c.Session["RefreshToken"] = t.Token.RefreshToken
...
```

If not how do I reassign the strings to create another structure to call Client.Get() ?

Comment: You could go the simple route and encode your data as a string using `encoding/json` for example.  Other options would be a base64 encoded gob.  Or just store the various pieces in the session individually like you show above, and use a couple helpers to store from a `t.Token` and recreate a `t.Token` from the session data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to "convert" structs to `string` and vice versa. Just know that only exported fields are serialized this way.

Since `oauth.Token` has only exported fields, this will work:

```
if data, err := json.Marshal(t.Token); err == nil {
    c.Session["Token"] = string(data)
} else {
    panic(err)
}
```

And this is how you can reconstruct the token from the session:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(c.Session["Token"]), &t.Token); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: I used jsonT, err := json.Marshal(t) and  var t *oauth.Transport
 json.Unmarshal([]byte(c.Session["jsonT"]), &t)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can try to save some string ID to `Session` and the object you need to `Cache`:

```
c.Session["id"] = id
go cache.Set("token_"+id, t.Token, 30*time.Minute)
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var token oauth.Token

id := c.Session["id"]
if err := cache.Get("token_"+id, &token); err != nil {
    // TODO: token not found, do something
}

// TODO: use your token here...
```

The advantage of this approach is you do not have to work with `json` package explicitly and cache has a few different back-ends out of the box: memory, redis, memcached. Moreover, you do not have a limitation of 4K as in case of `Cookie` based `Session`.

https://revel.github.io/manual/cache.html